# SELECT * FROM OPENXML IN STORED PROCEDURE returns empty row

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-openxml

I have a problem using openxml function in my stored procedure, as you can see, the select statement **returns empty row**. I suspect the sql couldn't read the xml directories.this is the first time i'm using this function, so i am not sure is this the right way to use it.btw i am using sql server 2008 r2. here's the code to reproduce the problem.

```
Declare @hddoc int
Declare @Doc xml 

SET @Doc = ' <DataSet>
     <tblEmp>
      <name>Nazri</name> 
      <designation>Developer</designation>  
    </tblEmp>
    <tblEmp>
      <name>Jibin</name> 
 <designation>System Analyst</designation> 
   </tblEmp>
          </DataSet>'

EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT @hddoc OUTPUT, @Doc

SELECT @hddoc

DECLARE @iDoc INT
SET @iDoc = 1

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@iDoc,'/Dataset/tblEmp')
   WITH ( name varchar(50) '@name',
   designation varchar(50) '@designation'
    )
```

Comment: I realize this is just a walking example but when you make the code production ready don't forget to call `sp_xml_removedocument` to release the document handle or else this will cause a resource leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the supplied table mapping is indicating the the values should be attributes; however, in the XML they are elements.  Change your `OPENXML` statement to be like the following and it should return the expected results.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@iDoc,'/DataSet/tblEmp',2)
   WITH ( name varchar(50) 'name',
   designation varchar(50) 'designation'
    )
```

basically the two changes are to specify element centric mapping and the update the relative xpath to looking for elements instead of attributes.

Comment: it works!. but can i use it like this in my store procs by calling the xml using openrowset? this is how intended to use it, but so far it doesn't work. can u try to look at this? thanks ted. 

---select from rowset here  
INSERT INTO tblEmp --(name,designation)
        SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@HANDLE, '/Dataset/tblEmp')      
        WITH (name VARCHAR(50) 'name',designation VARCHAR(50)     'designation')

Comment: You still have `Dataset` instead of `DataSet`.

Comment: @MuhammadNazri Yes `openxml` can be used within a stored procedure.   My typical use case was to push a batch of changes to an SP in a XML format then the proc can do whatever the business logic is off that dataset.

Comment: Thanks @RafałWojtaszek, that's a life saver. and thanks Ted, for sharing the tips. so i will mark this one as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddData
( @data XML)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    @handle INT,
    @PrepareXmlStatus INT

EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus= sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @Data

INSERT INTO tblEmp (name,designation)
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@handle,'/DataSet/tblEmp',2)
   WITH ( name varchar(50) 'name',
          designation varchar(50) 'designation')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle

END
```

Comment: thanks bro? but one question, but how can i use it with openrowset? what i mean is, i want to call the xml file from the disk, open it with openxml and then insert it to the table. 

can i use it like this?

    
INSERT INTO tblEmp --(name,designation)
        SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@HANDLE, '/Dataset/tblEmp')      
        WITH (name VARCHAR(50) 'name',designation VARCHAR(50) 'designation')

Comment: I change it to stored procedure. I hope is that what you need.